# potential minimising trajectory as geodesic in some metric space ?!

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

From a physical point of view, given a potential $\phi: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}$ a particle of velocity $v$ at a point $p$ would follow a trajectory $\gamma: I \to \mathbb{R}^4$ such that $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma'(0)=v - \nabla(\phi)$. [standard initial value specification]

So far so good.

Now, can I realise this trajectory as a geodesic in $\mathbb{R}^4$ w.r.t. some metric $g$ defined in its tangent bundle? Clearly if so, the metric should depend intrinsically on the potential ($- \nabla(\phi)$)?

i.e. Does there exist such a metric where geodesics are usual potential minimising trajectories w.r.t. the $\phi$? Although the metric is allowed to vary [and well-behaved potential $\phi$ is assumed]

Comment: Please, edit your question to explain what do you mean by a "well-behaved potential".

Comment: I meant $\phi$ is smooth

Comment: Ok, then the answer is negative, for instance, suppose that $v=\overrightarrow{0}$ and $\phi$ is nonconstant but has a critical point $p$, i.e. $\nabla \phi(p)=\overrightarrow{0}$ (say, the standard quadratic potential). Then you would have $\gamma'(t_0)=\overrightarrow{0}$ for $t_0$ such that $\gamma(t_0)=p$. But if a geodesic has derivative vanishing at one point, that  geodesic has to be constant.

Comment: can I not say the geodesic in this case is trivial, i.e. it maps the whole of its domain interval to a point, which is just a constant map, at $t_0$?

Comment: But then you are not describing the entire gradient line  as a geodesic since the entire gradient line is not a single point.